# How to set a Drop Down List in VBA that is dependent on the adjacent cell's values?

Tags: vba, drop-down-menu

On the first sheet, I have a Table called "Inventory" that has two columns. The First Column contains all the barcodes and the Second Column contains the Item's Description.

Example:

| Barcode | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1111 | Item 1 |
| 2222 | Item 2 |
| 3333 | Item 3 |
| 4444 | Item 4 |
| 2222 | Item 222 |

On the second sheet, I have a table called "Out" where you enter the barcode in a cell in the first column and the adjacent cell in the second column displays the Item's Description based on the barcode entered with the help of the formula vlookup.

At this point, I have encountered no problems and everything works great.

But some of the barcodes have multiple different descriptions (as shown in the example in the case of barcode "2222") and I want to be able to change the item's description with a drop down list that only shows the different items which have the same barcode.

For example if I enter the barcode "2222" the adjacent cell will show "Item 2". I want to install a drop down list on the Description Cell that will show Item 2 and Item 222 and select the one I want.

Can you help me solve this problem?

```
    Sub Data_Val()

    dim Inventory_Sheet, Out_Sheet as Worksheet

    set Inventory_sheet = Thisworkbook.worksheets("Inventory")
    set Out_Sheet = thisworkbook.worksheets("Out")

    Out_Sheet.activate

    Range("B2").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
         AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
         Operator:=xlBetween, _
         Formula1:="='Inventory'!$B$2:$B$6"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: Now, when you say "a Table" are you referring to a real `Table` (`ListObject`)? The same for the second sheet.

Comment: Yes I am referring to tables as ListObject
And the only thing that I have tried is With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="='Inventory_Table'!$B$2:$F$6"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With 

And this code shows all the Descriptions regardless of the Barcode entered.

Comment: Please, edit your question and place the code there! Such a code cannot be understood in a comment. I will prepare a piece of code using an event, in order to automatically create the necessary Validation, when something is changed in the inventory sheet. Please, name the sheet keeping the Table "Inventory", the same ("Inventory")...

Answer (score 0):

Please, use the next a approach:

1. The following code needs a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'. It can be handled without it, using late binding, but you will not benefit of the intellisense suggestions. Use the next code to automatically create it:

```
Sub addScrRunTimeRef()
  'Add a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime':
  'In case of error ('Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project not trusted'):
  'Options->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings->Macro Settings->Developer Macro Settings->
  '         check "Trust access to the VBA project object model"
  Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll"
End Sub
```

Run the code and save the workbook!

2. Create a `Public` variable in a **standard module**:

```
Public dictDescript As Scripting.Dictionary
```

3. Copy the next code in the "Inventory" sheet **code module**:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, arrT, i As Long
   Set rng = Me.ListObjects("Inventory").DataBodyRange
   If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        Set dictDescript = New Scripting.Dictionary
        arrT = rng.value                      'to make code faster
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrT)
            'update the dictionary
            If Not dictDescript.Exists(arrT(i, 1)) Then
                dictDescript.Add arrT(i, 1), arrT(i, 2)
            Else
                dictDescript(arrT(i, 1)) = dictDescript(arrT(i, 1)) & "|" & arrT(i, 2)
            End If
        Next i
   End If
End Sub
```

It will update the necessary dictionary when something is modified in the table.

4. Copy the next code in the sheet keeping "Out" table **code module**:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim rngO As Range
   Set rngO = Me.ListObjects("Out").DataBodyRange.Columns(1)
   
   If Not Intersect(Target, rngO) Is Nothing Then
       If dictDescript Is Nothing Then 'if nothing has been placed in the dictionary:
            Dim rng As Range, arrT, i As Long, strCondition As String
            Set rng = Worksheets("Inventory").ListObjects("Inventory").DataBodyRange
            Set dictDescript = New Scripting.Dictionary
             arrT = rng.value                      'to make code faster
             For i = 1 To UBound(arrT)
                 'update the dictionary
                 If Not dictDescript.Exists(arrT(i, 1)) Then
                     dictDescript.Add arrT(i, 1), arrT(i, 2)
                 Else
                     dictDescript(arrT(i, 1)) = dictDescript(arrT(i, 1)) & "," & arrT(i, 2)
                 End If
             Next i
        End If
       'return the validation list from the dictionary:
        strCondition = dictDescript(Target.value)
        If strCondition = "" Then  'if a wrong string has been inputed (not one of the barcodes in Inventory sheet)
            MsgBox Target.value & " barcode, does not exist in ""Inventory"" sheet...", vbInformation, _
                                                                                         "No appropriate barcode input"
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Validation.Delete: Target.Offset(0, 1).value = ""
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'create the validation:
        Target.Offset(0, 1).value = ""
        With Target.Offset(0, 1).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=strCondition
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Play with your barcodes and send some feedback.

Comment: @Anthony Didn't you find some time to test the above proposed solution? If tested, didn't it behave as you need?